# Spring Boot @Autowired Pros & Cons

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I can inject dependencies using 3 methods...

1. Property Injection
2. Setter Injection
3. Constructor Injection

Here are 3 basic examples of how classes that use each.

**Property Injection**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;


}
```

**Setter Injection**

```
import com.abc.foo.NotificationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PageController {

    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    public void setNotificationService(NotificationService notificationService) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
    }
}
```

**Constructor Injection**

```
import com.abc.foo.NotificationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PageController {

    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    public PageController(NotificationService notificationService) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
    }

}
```

My question is this: What is the preferred method and are there pros and cons to each?

Comment: I am sorry I was looking for questions regarding the property injection and that is why I didn't find it. When I use the property injection is it just creating a setter behind the scenes for me? or is this just voodoo magic :)

Comment: It sets the value of the field directly using reflection. Generally speaking, it's to be avoided as it makes testing difficult.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson ... that is exactly what i was in search of. Appreciate the help.